# Reducing SCNGeometry polygon count at runtime

Tags: 3d, scenekit, blender

I have a 3D model in Blender which has way too many polygons. Unfortunately I cannot use Blender to reduce the polygon count (e.g., through a Decimate modifier) due to Blender's limitations—it cannot apply the modifier to a object with shape keys.

So I was thinking I could probably simplify the mesh programmatically in SceneKit, and maybe export it afterwards.

I think the first step would be to figure out neighboring polygons I could somehow merge, and iteratively do this step. Then I'd enumerate the resulting polygons and figure out which vertex data was actually used, and create a new simplified `SCNGeometrySource`, and then a re-indexed `SCNGeometryElement`. Since the Blender shape keys are exported as `SCNMorpher` target geometries, I'd also have to make the corresponding changes to all of the target geometries so that their source vertex information matches up.

Does that sound reasonable? Is there an algorithm to use for merging neighboring polygons?

Comment: I'm looking to do something similar. Thought I'd add this in, in case anyone lands on this page like me. I'm looking at SCNLevelOfDetail. This might do what you want. Not putting it as an answer. But worthy of a comment.

Comment: This is a good overview of possible approaches to this: http://graphics.stanford.edu/courses/cs468-10-fall/LectureSlides/08_Simplification.pdf